# Jenkins - run console application

Tags: c#, jenkins, console-application, nancy

I created c# console application with self-hosted Nancy web service. Locally I can run this without any problem by launching exe file (by click or cmd) or using Visual Studio.

The question is how to launch that kind of application using Jenkins? It's a kind of service so it should be launched by Jenkins and run till another build.

**UPDATE**

So solution for me was use that command in 'Execute Windows batch command' window:

```
START "Process_Name" Path_To_Exe/File.exe
```

Also as first step I added killing this process (to not create with each build new instance of self hosted server):

```
TASKKILL /F /IM File.exe
exit 0
```

Comment: You mean you want this service running permanently on the jenkins server? Or you want to run this exe as part of the build?

Comment: @Rob - I thought about the second option - after build I just wanted to run the app (actually I did it, but I think after run it immediately stopped).

Comment: Right, but where will it be run? On the jenkins server or on the build machine?

Comment: It could be launched on the same server where it's builded.

Comment: Then you can just add it as a build step, no?

Comment: I believe it would be ok but I just noticed that probably I need to run this under admin rights.